# Tuplas de Python en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, estructuras-de-datos, vue.js

Tengo una tupla (o una lista) en Python, que funciona para llenar un control `<select>` en las plantillas de Django.

La tupla se ve de este modo en Python:

```
DOCUMENTO_GENERICO = (
    (0, 'FUAR y/o Sol. Ind.'),
    (1, 'Testimonial'),
    (2, 'Instancia administrativa'),
    (3, 'Demanda de juicio')
)
```

Pero ahora que intento usar JavaScript, me enfrento con un comportamiento que no puedo comprender. Hice una estructura similar en JavaScript:

```
docs: [
  {0: 'Solicitud Individual'},
  {1: 'Testimonial'},
  {2: 'Instancia administrativa'},
  {3: 'Demanda de juicio'}
]
```

Y la uso de la siguiente manera:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Tuplas en JavaScrirpt',
    docs: [
      {0: 'Solicitud Individual'},
      {1: 'Testimonial'},
      {2: 'Instancia administrativa'},
      {3: 'Demanda de juicio'}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ title }}
  <select name="documento" id="documento">
    <option  v-for="doc in docs" :value="doc[0]">{{ doc[1] }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Pensaba que en una línea `doc` encontraba una línea de `docs`, por ejemplo `{0: 'Solicitud Individual'}`, en Python, haría algo como `DOCUMENTO_GENERICO[0][1]` para obtener `Solicitud Individual`,  pero en JavaScript el resultado no es el esperado.

---

Quiero saber que estructura de datos puedo usar en JavaScript para reproducir el mismo comportamiento que uso en Python, porque esto arreglaría la forma en la que uso el control `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu caso de uso es atípico, porque no le estás pasando a `docs` un array de elementos homogéneos ni un objeto. A cambio le pasas un array de objetos que no son homogéneos entre sí.

Suponiendo que tu intención es efectivamente que las llaves de cada uno de tus objetos fuesen numéricas y correlativas, entonces lo que quieres hacer se hace asi:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Tuplas en JavaScrirpt',
    docs: [
      {0: 'Solicitud Individual'},
      {1: 'Testimonial'},
      {2: 'Instancia administrativa'},
      {3: 'Demanda de juicio'}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ title }}
  <select name="documento" id="documento">
    <option  v-for="(doc,index) in docs" :value="index">{{ doc[index] }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Pero de ser así, entonce sería más eficiente haber declarado

```
docs: [
   'Solicitud Individual',
   'Testimonial',
   'Instancia administrativa',
   'Demanda de juicio'
]
```

Así que supongo que en realidad la tupla de Python podría traer cualquier ID, no necesariamente correlativos. Por ejemplo:

```
DOCUMENTO_GENERICO = (
    (0, 'FUAR y/o Sol. Ind.'),
    (10, 'Testimonial'),
    (20, 'Instancia administrativa'),
    (30, 'Demanda de juicio')
)
```

En cuyo caso debieras usar la propiedad `docs` como un objeto:

```
docs: {
    0: 'Solicitud Individual',
    10: 'Testimonial',
    20: 'Instancia administrativa',
    30: 'Demanda de juicio'
}
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Tuplas en JavaScrirpt',
    docs: {
     0: 'Solicitud Individual',
        10: 'Testimonial',
        20: 'Instancia administrativa',
        30: 'Demanda de juicio'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ title }}
  <select name="documento" id="documento">
    <option  v-for="(value,key) in docs" :value="key">{{ value }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El objetivo es Python es que el valor a la izquierda (en este caso son números, pero puede ser otra cosa) se almacena en la base de datos. El de la derecha es el valor mostrado en el control. Como voy a migrar datos existentes, debo asegurarme que sigan siendo válidos.

Comment: Eso pensé, por eso mi segundo ejemplo parece ser lo que estabas buscando.